# Solr geographical search

Tags: solr, lucene, gis

i am testing solr query for geographical search, this is my query:

```
 SolrQuery query =new SolrQuery();
        query.setParam("q","*:*");
        query.setParam("fq","geofilt");
        query.setParam("d","100000");
        query.setParam("pt","51.53750834,-0.19329616");
        query.setParam("sfield","location_s");
```

i am getting no results although there is very near points and also exact point to the pt.
any idea whats the reason??

hint: im using this field type for spatial search (the one comes in the schema.xml by default):

```
<fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
        geo="true" distErrPct="0.025" maxDistErr="0.000009" units="degrees" />
```

because when i try to use this one as mentioned in the solr website i get an error:

```
<fieldType name="location_rpt"   class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"                  spatialContextFactory="com.spatial4j.core.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory"
               autoIndex="true"
               distErrPct="0.025"
               maxDistErr="0.000009"
               units="degrees" />
```

and this is my field definition:

```
<field name="location_s" type="location_rpt" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

instead of this kind of field names please add only 1 field that served for both x/y :

```
<dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

That will allow you to put directly datas in solr geo format :

```
  "env": "DEV",
        "latlgn_0_coordinate": -2.6263,
        "latlgn_1_coordinate": -44.1978,
```

please take a look to both [solr spatialsearch](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search) & [solr wiki spatialsearch](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch)

Comment: thanks, but one needed configuration is to add this to schema.xml:<fieldType name="location_rpt"   class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
               spatialContextFactory="com.spatial4j.core.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory"
               distErrPct="0.025"
               maxDistErr="0.000009"
               units="degrees"
            />    but when i do this i get solr error "class not fount error" and "noclassDefFound"!!

Comment: Ah ok, so you will need to put the solr jts lib in your classpath by adding it to your class path or putting it in your project as a library (under a web project referenced it in web.xml)

Answer (score 0):

As said above, please make sure to have in your runtime classpath.
You might download and install in your path the JTS library : [JTS Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/)

**Solr Manual** [solr install documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4)

> The JTS jar file must be on Solr's classpath as well. Due to a
>   combination of things, JTS can't simply be referenced by a ""
>   entry in solrconfig.xml; it needs to be in WEB-INF/lib in Solr's war
>   file, basically.

enjoy :)

Comment: **Similar issue from stackoverflow**: [stackoverflow issue #1][3]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks jean, it worked with me without using JTS library, solr schema comes already with this field type that I used:

```
 <fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
   geo="true" distErrPct="0.025" maxDistErr="0.000009" units="degrees" />
```

I defined a field of that type and it worked. This is my query:

```
 SolrQuery query =new SolrQuery();
        query.set("q","*:*");
        query.set("fq","{!geofilt}");
        query.set("pt","32.014708,35.873725");
        query.set("sfield","location");
        query.set("d","100");
```

Thanks.